# In SQL, does "+" just mean positive?

Tags: sql

In the following query:

```
SELECT * from TABLE
WHERE Amount = +1;
```

Does the "+" sign just mean positive?

Is there a technical difference between using that query with or without the sign?

According to a similar question in a [different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353076/what-does-a-plus-sign-in-a-sql-where-clause-where-username-system-user),

> unary plus operator will convert a string argument to a number. When applied to a constant string filled with digits, this could actually be beneficial as a way of encouraging the compiler to use an index on a numeric field.

That answer was given in a different context, but may answer my question too.

Comment: In that context, yes - it's the [`+` unary operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174362.aspx) (documentation is for SQL Server but I;d suspect it would be the same for almost any other server software.

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using