# Plus sign in the select clause of an SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on an old SQL written for Oracle. There is a part of the select clause that I do not understand, even after googling and checking the questions related to the + sign with the key words Oracle and SQL.

I have checked the answer for a similar question for the where clause [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217293/what-does-a-sign-mean-in-an-oracle-sql-where-clause) and I found an Oracle docs for the join as well, but it does not make sense for the select clause.

Given an SQL below what is the purpose of the plus sign.

```
select '01,'|| 
lpad( 
   (select nvl(count(*), 0) from table1)
   +
   (select nvl(count(*), 0) from table2)
   +
   (select nvl(count(*), 0) from table3)
,9,'0')
from DUAL
```

The sample output

```
01,000011111
```

From a sample sql output, it seems that it is for concatenating a result, but I want to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `+` is not for string concatenation.  It is for addition.  Plus, `count()` does not return `NULL` values so `nvl()` is not needed.

This should be equivalent:

```
select ('01,' || 
        lpad( ((select count(*) from table1) +
               (select count(*) from table2) +
               (select count(*) from table3)
              ), 9, '0'
            )
        )
from DUAL
```

Comment: Could you also please let me know if this + operator in the select clause oracle specific?

Comment: @Rovshen: the `+` operator is the standard operator in SQL to add numbers. Why do you think that it would be something "special". What operator would you expect to be responsible for adding numbers?

Comment: Good point, I haven't had a need to do arithmetic in a select statement. Thank you for confirming!

Comment: I think he’s confused with the non-ISO outer join notation used optionally by Oracle, which also uses the operator +

Answer (score 1):

Rovshen, I agree with Gordon.  The code is concatenating the '01,' to the formatted sum of the counts from three tables.  The LPAD is zero filling the summed number value to 9 digits. "||" is the concatenation symbol in Oracle though there is also a concat function.  It is rarely used.

Comment: Thank you Mark, thanks for explaining the rest of the sql, I had to look up LPAD.