# Sanity Check: (+) Operator in WHERE Clause for Oracle DB?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Oracle “(+)” Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020786/oracle-operator)

So I was given a script with the following:

```
SELECT BLAH
  FROM A_TABLE T1, A_TABLE T2, A_TABLE T3 
 WHERE T2.FIELD_1(+) = T1.FIELD_1
   AND T3.FIELD_1(+) = T2.FIELD_1
   ... etc a few more AND clauses that do that same thing
```

I need to convert this script to MSSQL Server but I have no clue what this operator is doing. Is it possible that this is some kind of typo?

Comment: I *think* that's Oracle-speak for a left join, the `(+)` indicating you get all the T2s even if they don't match the T1s.  I might have it backwards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle "(+)" Operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020786/oracle-operator).  Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425960/oracle-old-joins-a-tool-script-for-conversion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the old Oracle syntax for outer joins. You should use the ANSI join syntax instead:

```
SELECT BLAH
  FROM A_TABLE T1
  LEFT JOIN A_TABLE T2 ON T2.FIELD_1 = T1.FIELD_1
  LEFT JOIN A_TABLE T3 ON T3.FIELD_1 = T2.FIELD_1
 WHERE ... etc
```

Answer (score 3):

It is the Oracle notation for LEFT JOIN.

It means

```
SELECT BLAH
  FROM A_TABLE T1
  LEFT JOIN A_TABLE T2 ON T2.FIELD_1 = T1.FIELD_1
  LEFT JOIN A_TABLE T3 ON T3.FIELD_1 = T2.FIELD_1
   ... etc a few more AND clauses that do that same thing
```

The (+) is put against the optional side. Read also:

- http://www.dba-oracle.com/art_sql_iso_99.htm
- [Difference between Oracle's plus (+) notation and ansi JOIN notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193654/different-between-oracles-plus-notation-over-ansi-join-notation)