# (+) syntax for outer joins in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, outer-join

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Oracle “(+)” Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020786/oracle-operator)
>   [Oracle (Old?) Joins - A tool/script for conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425960/oracle-old-joins-a-tool-script-for-conversion)

I have been somewhat spoiled by using Oracle for years.  Now I am using mysql and cannot find a non-ansi version/shorthand version of outer joins in MySQL.

In oracle I could do this

```
select a.country acountry,
        a.stateProvince aStateProvince,
        b.countryName bcountry,
        b.name bstateProvince
  from User a,
          stateprovince b
  where a.country*=b.countryName **(+)**
          and a.stateProvince*=b.name **(+)**
```

to get an outer join.  Can mysql do something similar?

Comment: I am curious. Why would you want to use non-ansi syntax? Ansi syntax is much easier to understand, especially in complex queries.

Comment: You can do one join per line with the oracle style join.  I cannot remember where the (+) goes though.

Comment: Actually, what you have there is not an outer join...

Comment: @Bohemian: it IS a left outer join in Oracle 8.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle "(+)" Operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020786/oracle-operator).  Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425960/oracle-old-joins-a-tool-script-for-conversion

Comment: @ypercube, it's still a left outer join in Oracle 11g, too, if you must use it ;-)

Comment: `spoiled by using Oracle`: I can only imagine the horrible things that must have occurred to corrupt a developer so deeply as to make that statement.

Answer (score 3):

Simpler than this:

```
select a.country acountry,
        a.stateProvince aStateProvince,
        b.countryName bcountry,
        b.name bstateProvince
  from User a
        left join
          stateprovince b
    on  a.country = b.countryName 
          and a.stateProvince = b.name
```

No.

Comment: The `(+)` notation is definitely more complex to understand.  The SQL-92 join notations (that's 20 year's old next year!) takes a bit of getting used to at first, but is much better once mastered, which is usually only a matter of a few days work.