# Can I left join two tables without using ON clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Is it valid if I try doing a `LEFT JOIN` between two tables without using an `ON` clause. How does the SQL engine treat such joins? Would it be treated as a `CROSS JOIN` or will I be getting an error.

Comment: "or will I be getting an error" --- what if you put any effort to your problem **before** you ask?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use mysql JOIN without ON condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470942/can-i-use-mysql-join-without-on-condition)

Comment: I dont have a working laptop and I posted the ques from my mobile.. sorry about that...

Comment: SQLfiddle works on a smartphone

Comment: Rather than jumping straight to which keywords you'll randomly append together in the hopes of getting your desired result - maybe explain to us what you're doing and what results you're hoping to achieve. Hopefully, with sample data and a table of expected results.

Comment: **NO.** I add more simply to get past the minimum length.

Comment: Please wait for @Teja response before declaring this as duplicate.

Comment: There's a NON-ANSI compliant format you could use if you absolutely want to avoid using an ON clause (though why would be beyond me). `SELECT * FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1.ID = t2.F_ID`. Keep in mind this will work for INNER joins, but will give different results if you'd try doing an OUTER join.

Comment: @SchmitzIT I don't recall MySQL having an non-ansi outer join syntax like Oracle's (+)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658334/syntax-for-outer-joins-in-mysql  so I don't see the relevance of proposing the old-style inner join

Comment: @Used_By_Already That's the issue when an OP flags it with different tags ;) I went for straight SQL. Didn't consider MySQL (or Postgres, for that matter).

Answer (score 15):

If I'm guessing your intention right -
It seems you are looking for something similar to `CROSS JOIN` but you still want to return the left side even if the  right side is empty.
You can indeed implement this using `LEFT JOIN`.
For `LEFT JOIN` you must have `ON` but you can use `ON TRUE`.

---

```
create table t1 (i int);
insert into t1 (i) values (1),(2),(3);
create table t2 (i int);
```

---

```
select * from t1 cross join t2;
```

(empty result set)

---

```
select * from t1 left join t2 on true;
```

---

```
i i      
- ------ 
1 (null) 
2 (null) 
3 (null)
```

Comment: Which causes the join to be the equivalent of a cross join...... there simply is no point to using left join without a qualification to that join where some rows are matched and some might not be matched. ON TRUE does not permit some rows to be unmatched.

Comment: There is a single "edge case" where `left join on true` would permit rows to be returned but where `cross join` would not. I had not considered that edge case in my earlier reply. For my omission I apologize. However if you re-read that reply it states `there simply is no point` and there is no practical reason for having a table with no rows 'left joined on true' to a table with rows. And, it is still not possible to have a left join without ON (which was the question)

Comment: @Used_By_Already - You'll probably want to take a look at the following post :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41010016/how-to-get-dummy-value-for-xml-empty-tag-in-table-using-oracle/41011346#41011346

Answer (score 0):

While Dudu's code is admittedly neat, I did have to actually run it to figure out what it does.

It seems to me you have two scenarios i.e. (1) empty table and (2) non-empty table. The table expressions for each can be `union`ed together. This may make things easier to understand.

Also, I would recommend you avoid nulls; three-valued logic is not worth the bother. Here I'm guessing a default value of `-99` is suitable:

```
create table t1 (c1 int);
insert into t1 values (1),(2),(3);
create table t2 (c2 int);

select c1, c2
  from t1 CROSS JOIN t2
union
select c1, -99 as c2
  from t1
 where not exists ( select * from t2 );
```

Comment: t1, t2 --> t1 cross join t2 (not a must, but clarifies that this not an old style join with accidental omitted join condition)

Comment: union --> union all (union will eliminate duplications that might exist in t1 or t2)

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz: have restored the `CROSS JOIN` version to my answer. Usage of `union` is by design i.e. don't want duplicates!

Comment: Take a look at this :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41010016/how-to-get-dummy-value-for-xml-empty-tag-in-table-using-oracle/41011346#41011346