# How to get dummy value for XML empty tag in table using Oracle?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

```
select a.test 
from demotable b
    ,XMLTable('//test' passing xmltype(b.xmlTagColumn) columns test varchar(10) path '.') a
```

b.xmlTagColumn has xml content. 
If b.xmlTagColumn has `<test></test>` then I am not getting anything from above statement not even null. How can I get null or dummy value for empty tag?

Comment: Please add a tag for database+version

Answer (score 1):

`left join ... on 1=1`

---

```
select  a.test 

from                demotable b 

        left join   XMLTable
                    (
                        '//test' 
                        passing xmltype(b.xmlTagColumn) 
                        columns 
                            test varchar(10) path '.'
                    ) a 

        on         1=1
;
```

---

Demo

```
create table demotable (id int,xmlTagColumn varchar2(100));

insert into demotable (id,xmlTagColumn) values (1,'<X><test>123</test></X>');
insert into demotable (id,xmlTagColumn) values (2,'<Y><test>456</test></Y>');
insert into demotable (id,xmlTagColumn) values (3,'<Z><prod>123</prod></Z>');
```

---

```
select  b.id
       ,a.test 

from                demotable b 

        left join   XMLTable
                    (
                        '//test' 
                        passing xmltype(b.xmlTagColumn) 
                        columns 
                            test varchar(10) path '.'
                    ) a 

        on         1=1
;
```

---

```
+----+--------+
| ID | TEST   |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 123    |
+----+--------+
| 2  | 456    |
+----+--------+
| 3  | (null) |
+----+--------+
```

Comment: trying to make sense of this via http://rextester.com/IJCW99069 but getting ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'XMLTYPE'

Comment: I'll add a small demo in a few minutes