# Joining Three Tables using Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables as follows:

```
table 1          table 2          table 3
-------          -------          -------
a                a                a
b                c                c
c                f                
d
e
f
```

I want to join this three tables into 1 which will result to the following:

```
result table
------------

a               a                a
b
c               c                c
d
e
f               f
```

Noticed that the second and third col contains blank row if it does not have a match.  How can I achieve this using oracle sql?

Comment: This is a homework question. Please tell what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Tomalak I tried using select * from table1, table2, table3 where table1.primarykey = table2.primarykey and table2.primarykey = table3.primarykey

Comment: @OMG Ponies I use the (+) but doesn't achive what I desired.

Comment: That's extremely old syntax - there are [questions to explain how to convert it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425960/oracle-old-joins-a-tool-script-for-conversion)

Comment: @OM Ponies, my problem with the on statement is it will only join table given a primary key. I'm working on an ETL type of system that does not have primary key. It needs four or more columns in order for me to join tables

Comment: You don't help yourself by abstracting that in your question details.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON ( table1.name = table2.name )
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 ON ( table1.name = table3.name )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 -- Enhance table
 alter table table1 add (field2 /*e.g.*/ varchar2(10)
                        ,field3 /*e.g.*/ varchar2(10) );

 -- update rows roughly works like this. (I don't exactly know your column names, primary keys, etc)
 update table1 o set o.field2 = (select i.field from table2
                                 where o.field1 = i.field);
```