# In Oracle, in regards to syntax - how do I convert the (+) syntax to modern conventional JOIN?

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join, outer-join

Suppose I have  a FROM clause like so :

```
  FROM 

      apps.po_requisition_lines_all prl,  
      apps.po_requisition_headers_all prha,  
      po.po_req_distributions_all prda,  
      po.po_distributions_all pda,  
      po.po_headers_all pha 
  where 1=1  
      and prl.requisition_header_id= prha.requisition_header_id 
      and prl.requisition_line_id= prda.requisition_line_id 
      and prda.distribution_id= pda.req_distribution_id(+) 
      and pha.po_header_id(+)=pda.po_header_id
```

Then how does this type of OUTER JOIN get converted if we want to use normal JOIN syntax ? thanks !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle (Old?) Joins - A tool/script for conversion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425960/oracle-old-joins-a-tool-script-for-conversion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the schema, I find it difficult but this should set you in the right direction:

```
 FROM apps.po_requisition_lines_all prl 
 INNER JOIN apps.po_requisition_headers_all prha ON prl.requisition_header_id = prha.requisition_header_id 
 INNER JOIN po.po_req_distributions_all     prda ON prda.requisition_line_id  = prl.requisition_line_id
 LEFT  JOIN po.po_distributions_all         pda  ON prda.distribution_id      = pda.req_distribution_id 
-- I note from the example provided that this is a right join
-- Without seeing the schema, it looks to me as though it should be left
-- As I say say, without seeing the schema, I probably shouldn't pass comment
 RIGHT JOIN po.po_headers_all               pha  ON pha.po_header_id          = pda.po_header_id;
```

For an `INNER JOIN` you can just say `JOIN` although I think that explicitly saying `INNER` aids readability. I also note the example provided has `WHERE 1=1` which is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

The ***+*** is old version of `Outer Joins`, and it differs where the ***+*** comes after equality sign or before it, But now it's recommended to use `Join` keywords instead of `+`, about the **+** sign if it comes:

After **=**:

```
select * from t1, t2
where t1.id=t2.id(+)
```

This means **Left Outer Join**:

```
select * from t1
left outer join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
```

---

Before **=**:

```
select * from t1, t2
where t1.id(+)=t2.id
```

This means **Right Outer Join**:

```
select * from t1
Right outer join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
```

---

Without **+**:

```
select * from t1, t2
where t1.id=t2.id
```

This means **Inner Join**:

```
select * from t1
join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
```